# In iPhone application can we add any such key to the keybord which when pressed will remove the keyboard from the view?

Tags: iphone

I have a table view in which there are almost 16 text boxes where in i am taking input from the user but once the we are done with the editing of the textboxes the keyboard should hide which is not happening.I saw in one application where we can have an costume keyboard and add an key/button to it on click of which the key board will get removed from the view?any one have any idea...

Comment: but that does not look good design vise dude....ok leave any solution to hide picker view ..not abruptly but it will be removed from view in proper manner...any solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup textfield like the following code, particularly add event on **UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit** and set returnKeyType to **UIReturnKeyDone**

```
//username text
    UITextField* usernameTF=[[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90,40,210,31)] autorelease];
    usernameTF.placeholder=@"Username";
    [usernameTF setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0]];
    [usernameTF setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    usernameTF.clearsOnBeginEditing=TRUE;
    usernameTF.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically==TRUE;
    usernameTF.clearButtonMode=TRUE;
    [usernameTF setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [usernameTF setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    usernameTF.contentHorizontalAlignment=TRUE;
    usernameTF.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;
    [usernameTF addTarget:self action:@selector(textOver:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
```

and then on selector action implement this method-

```
-(IBAction)textOver:(id)sender{ 
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: This works only for normal keyboard and not for number pad dude...any solution

Comment: @breakfreehg hey used navigationController and when you touch on textfield(phone number or zip code). number format keyboard pop up(write method on event UIControlEventEditingDidBegin), add done button to the right side of navigation control, add touch event on Done button, on touch call the textOver method with the sender object(phoneNumberTF) and remover Done button from right side of navigationController once keyboard disappear.

Comment: but that does not look good design vise dude....ok leave any solution to hide picker view ..not abruptly but it will be removed from view in proper manner...any solution..

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add done button to numeric keypad then check out the following link
http://www.neoos.ch/news/46-development/54-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key
it works for me.
let me know if you have any problem.